# Angular.js model not updateing after first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an example here:
http://www.search-this.com/examples/angular-help/

If you double-click "Text Message" in the list it brings up an input box.
type "one" in the input box and click the update button.
Notice the console.log
click SmsResponseActionParmAndValue to expand and locate the "Text Message" option
click ParmAndValue to expand and notice the Value property has our "one" value we typed in.

Now type two in the input box and look at the console.log and notice it doesn't update? It only updates the first time?

Help please...

Comment: You should post the code that is needed to understand your problem on SO. The link will probably change and nobody will understand what this was about.

Comment: code here too: https://jsfiddle.net/8evuoqLz/1/

Answer (score 0):

which is getting updated in selected object not in main JSON object.

$scope.updateDetails = function () {

```
    console.log("update");
    console.log($scope.actions); //
    console.log($scope.selectedAction); // look in this object updated you have to override it to original object or use 2 times ng-repeat to bind.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very ugly i know but its a solution:

```
   $scope.updateDetails = function() {

      angular.forEach($scope.actions.SmsResponseActionParmAndValue,function(action){
          if(action.Description === $scope.selectedAction.Description){
               console.log($scope.selectedAction)
               action.ParmAndValue = $scope.selectedAction.ParmAndValue
               return;
          }
      });

      console.log($scope.actions)
   };
```

The problem is that the updated model doesn't point to the same array in memory as the original object so we have to update the array that the original object points to.

Comment: but it updates once, just fine... But not more than once... It's the same array... I think the answer is in $digest(). But I don't know enough yet...

Comment: This is strange because for me it doesn't update when button pressed.The value of "Text Message" is an empty string when you do console.log in $scope.updateDetails. This is on Chrome 48.0.2564.103 (64-bit) on linux, but i dont know if this has to do something with the results...